# Activity indicator not showing in iOS 6

Tags: objective-c, ios

Inside my (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application method in my app's delegate, I have the following code to display an activity indicator:

```
spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
spinner.alpha = 1.0;
spinner.center = self.window.center;
spinner.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
spinner.layer.shadowRadius = 1;
spinner.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
spinner.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
[self.window addSubview:spinner];
```

The above code works fine in iOS 5 and earlier. However, the activity indicator doesn't display in iOS 6. 
How can I modify the above code so that the activity indicator is shown for iOS 6 as well?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a root view controller? If so, how is it created? It's possible that its view is on top of your spinner.

Answer (score 0):

try to add the last two lines to your code:

```
spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
spinner.alpha = 1.0;
spinner.center = self.window.center;
spinner.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
spinner.layer.shadowRadius = 1;
spinner.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
spinner.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
[self.window addSubview:spinner];


[spinner setHidden:YES];
[spinner startAnimating];
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that no views will display in the UI until the `applicationDidFinishLaunching:withOptions:` method returns. You cannot set a `UIActivityIndicatorView` and expect it to show instantly. iOS will not update the UI until the current run loop finishes. Ostensibly your `Default.png` is being displayed during the execution of `applicationDidFinishLaunching:withOptions:` and your `rootViewController` will not take over the UI until that method is complete.

If you wish to show a `UIActivityIndicatorView` over your `Default.png` to indicate to the user that the app is starting, then you can do something like this:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"]];
spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
spinner.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 60.0, 60.0);
spinner.center = CGPointMake(imageView.center.x, imageView.center.y);

spinner.alpha = 1.0;
spinner.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
spinner.layer.shadowRadius = 1;
spinner.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
spinner.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
[spinner startAnimating];
[imageView addSubview:spinner];
[self.window addSubview:imageView];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];    

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // The rest of your method here
    // Be sure to remove the UIImageView from the window when the processing is complete.
});
```

This way the `applicationDidFinishLaunching:withOptions:` will return control back to iOS and the view will be displayed. Once you've loaded your `rootViewController`, you can remove the `imageView` from the window.

Also, it's not a good idea to add the `UIActivityIndicatorView` directly to the `UIWindow`, but rather you should add it to a pre-existing view that is already a subView of the window like I demonstrated above.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line:

```
[spinner performSelector:@selector(startAnimating) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0f];
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when using a `UIActivityIndicatorView` in a `UITableViewCell`.
The problem was that calling the `startAnimating` method on cell creation wasn't working.

To solve this I called the `startAnimating` method in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

This is probably the same with calling `startAnimating` in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`. You need to call this when the window is actually being displayed. A timer could work, or even better, create a `UIViewController` and put the spinner in that view.